# show that $X_n=X_k$ in a convergent monotone sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Can someone help me with this:

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a convergent monotone sequence. Suppose there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim X_n=X_k$. Show that $X_n=X_k$ for all $n \geq k$.

Comment: Here is the magical [MathJax Handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  May need to use it to clear up the question.

Comment: Hint: Use that the sequence is monotone. And convergent.

Comment: Why do you even need the monotone condition?

Comment: @Nameless consider the sequence $S_1=0$, $S_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\ge2$ this is convergent and satisfies all of the hypothesis except that it isn't monotonic, while the conclusion is false

Comment: @Alessandro, I must be missing something, but doesn't convergence admit the existence of $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|X_n - X_k| < \epsilon $ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and all $n \geq k$?

Comment: @nameless Yes, but that doesn't imply that the sequence is constant after a point $X_k$, where $X_k$ is equal to the limit, which is what the question is about, you also need the sequence to be monotone for that to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence (the decreasing case is basically the same) with limit $L$.

Let $k$ be the least integer such that $X_k=L$ and suppose $X_{k+1}\neq L$, since the sequence is increasing for every $m>k$ we have $X_m-X_k\ge X_{k+1}-X_k$, that is $X_m-L$ is bigger than a strictly positive number.
Can you see how this contradicts the definition of limit of a sequence and conclude from there?